# Which grant type should I use for my React Native App to authenticate with Identity Server 4?

Tags: react-native, identityserver4

I am developing a reactive native app that needs to connect to my identity server 4 (.net c##) in my backend.

My login page is sitting on the IdentityServer>

I have one SAP web client and one react native client that want to connect to my IdentityServer. Whenever user clicks on login, they will be redirected to my login page in the IdentityServer.

In the SAP web client, I use the `implicit` flow for it since it is recommended.
For the react native mobile client, I'm not sure which flow should be recommended. I know that `client_credentials` would not be recommended since it is exposing my `access token` in the public.

What would be the recommended flow to use for my react native app in this case ? Thank you

Comment: Implicit grant is not recommended now https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#name-implicit-grant

Answer (score 2):

Its recommended to use code flow with PKCE over implicit flow even for SPA but older articles show implicit implementation. please read [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/aspnetcore2/topics/grant_types.html#:%7E:text=In%20the%20implicit%20flow%2C%20all,apps%2C%20and%20this%20shows%20JavaScript.&text=For%20JavaScript%2Dbased%20applications%2C%20Implicit%20is%20not%20recommended%20anymore.)

> For JavaScript-based applications, Implicit is not recommended
> anymore. Use Authorization Code with PKCE instead.

Note: please refer to newest articles for authorization and authentication.